# Highlight all occurrences of a name/word in a table when one observation is scrolled over

Tags: r, interactive, kable

I'm using Kable to create a handful of tables that show the most common drugs for people across varying forms of insurance.

[image: Barebones Table Example]

When someone scrolls over a drug, I'd like to be able to highlight where that drug appears elsewhere on the table for people to quickly compare positions across insurance categories. For instance, if someone scrolls over Harvoni in the Medicare column, the position of Harvoni should be highlight/pop-out in the other two 'Drug Name' columns. Has anyone come across an additional package with this capability?

I've tried, and failed, to figure it out using some combination of 'cell_spec' calls. Tableau also doesn't seem to have this feature. The alternative would be to use 'cell_spec' to color code specific drug names, but I've tried this and it looks way too messy/hectic. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Code for the table as it currently stands:

```
 kable(Table) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("hover")) %>%
  column_spec(3, bold = F, border_left = T) %>%
  column_spec(5, bold = F, border_left = T) %>%
  add_header_above(c("Large Employer" = 2, "Medicare Part D" = 2, "Medicaid" = 2)) %>%
  add_header_above(c("Plan Type" = 6)) %>%
  row_spec(0:12, align = "c") %>%
  row_spec(11:12, bold = T, color = "black") %>%
  footnote(general = "Dollar amounts in billions. Total drug spending does not account for rebates.")
```